# Do Azure Logic Apps support oneOf, anyOf in JSON schema validation

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I was trying to add JSON schema validation with in a Logic App using ParseJSON action.
I want to validate the existence of either of the object in the message (equivalent to XSD choice).

For instance, messages may have either of lastname or familyname.

```
{
"name": "Alan",
"familyname": "Turing"
}
```

Or

```
{
"name": "Alan",
"lastname": "Turing"
}
```

I modified the generated schema as,

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            {
                "familyname": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Logic App execution throws below error

[image: Logic App JSON oneOf]

Just to test if any other schema combination keywords works, tried to test with **anyOf** in place of **oneOf** and it fails in execution as well.

[image: Logic App JSON anyOf]

Does Logic Apps support these extended validation ? Am I missing some specific syntax here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are validating that either familyname or lastname be present then you are missing the "required" attribute.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "familyname": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "required": [ "familyname" ]
        },
        {
            "lastname": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "required": [ "lastname" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will validate the JSON. If you want to get the values out in a later step you could use the coalesce function.

```
@coalesce(actionBody('Parse_JSON')?['familyname'], actionBody('Parse_JSON')?['lastname'])
```